# Using wpdb in Wordpress to Insert a row

Tags: insert, wordpress

Does anyone see anything wrong with what I am doing here? I haven't worked with the database expressions in WP yet. All of my code runs except when I start to try to add items to tables I have created in the WP database. Any info would be greatly appreciated.  To me it seems that this syntax is correct and should run.

```
$wpdb->insert($wpdb->prefix . 'venue', array('event_id' => $event_id, 
                                    'event_date' => $event_date, 
                                    'venue_name' => $venue_name, 
                                    'venue_city' => $venue_city, 
                                    'ticket_url' => $ticket_url, 
                                    'event_url' => $event_url), 
                                array(%d, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) );
```

Many thanks.

UPDATE!: There seems to be an issue connecting to the WP database from within an AJAX call.  I am using jQuery to call a php file and trying this within the PHP file.  This does not seem to work as maybe the $wpdb class is outside of the scope?

Comment: What does it return? Wrap it in a `var_dump()` to get more details. Or turn on `WP_DEBUG` in your config file.

Comment: @Jason, I haven't had any luck from either.  Debug doesn't seem to report any errors and var_dump produces nothing.  It seems that everything will run with this line commented out but as soon as I comment it in nothing works.

Comment: Please see above update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values in the array containing the fieldtypes should be between `'` and `'`.

So that would become:

```
array('%d', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')
```

Instead of:

```
array(%d, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
```

Hope this can be of help for others having this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!isset($wpdb)){
$wpdb = new wpdb("user","pass","mydb",localhost);
}
```

Try it with this code on top?